# check capital words in text and extract it

Tags: r, gsub

I want to extract all capital words from the text. Lets say my data is like-->

```
Text<-c('I am JAY','I AM NOT HAPPY','YOU ARE IRRITATING','so Funny','hEY)
```

So output should be like -->

```
> output
```

[1] "I JAY"                "I AM NOT HAPPY"     "YOU ARE IRRITATING" "" ""

Please help me for this.

Comment: Why is the first value not "I JAY"? Are you just looking to extract "words" (how are you defining that--by word boundaries?) or any upper-case character?

Comment: I eddited my question, plz check again @AnandaMahto

Comment: @jay_phate Please show all the possible patterns, rather than changing it many times.

Comment: Next time please determine all the rules before you ask the question

Comment: @RichardScriven, or ask a comment before answering--it's not a race, you know ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(Text, '\\b[A-Z]+\\b'), paste, collapse=' ')
# [1] "I JAY"              "I AM NOT HAPPY"     "YOU ARE IRRITATING"
#[4] ""                   ""
```

Or

```
 gsub("[a-z][A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z][a-z]+", '', Text)
 #[1] "I  JAY"             "I AM NOT HAPPY"     "YOU ARE IRRITATING"
 #[4] " "                  ""
```

#### data

```
 Text<-c('I am JAY','I AM NOT HAPPY','YOU ARE IRRITATING','so Funny','hEY')
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, I edited my Text variable, Please see last variable.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.