# How can I retrive the gene names from the abstracts

Tags: python, r, pubmed

```
abstract.txt = "The insulin-like growth factor 1 (IGF1) signaling pathway has emerged as a major
```

regulator of the aging process, from rodents to humans. However, given the
pleiotropic actions of IGF1, its role in the aging brain remains complex and
controversial. While IGF1 is clearly essential for normal development of the
central nervous system, conflicting evidence has emerged from preclinical and
human studies regarding its relationship to cognitive function, as well as
cerebrovascular and neurodegenerative disorders. This review delves into the
current state of the evidence examining the role of IGF1 in the aging brain,
encompassing preclinical and clinical studies. A broad examination of the data
indicates that IGF1 may indeed play opposing roles in the aging brain, depending 
on the underlying pathology and context. Some evidence suggests that in the
setting of neurodegenerative diseases that manifest with abnormal protein
deposition in the brain, such as Alzheimer's disease, reducing IGF1 signaling may
serve a protective role by slowing disease progression and augmenting clearance
of pathologic proteins to maintain cellular homeostasis. In contrast, inducing
IGF1 deficiency has also been implicated in dysregulated function of cognition
and the neurovascular system, suggesting that some IGF1 signaling may be
necessary for normal brain function. Furthermore, states of acute neuronal
injury, which necessitate growth, repair and survival signals to persevere,
typically demonstrate salutary effects of IGF1 in that context. Appreciating the 
dual, at times opposing 'Dr Jekyll' and 'Mr Hyde' characteristics of IGF1 in the 
aging brain, will bring us closer to understanding its impact and devising more
targeted IGF1-related interventions.
"

This is my text file abtract of pubmed. this abstract contains some gene names. how can I retrive gene names

Comment: Have a look at the package `tm` in R

Comment: I am having bunch of pubmed abstracts as  a text file  is related to cancer. now from this I need to extract the gene names avilable in these abstracts.  how can I get?

Comment: @Venkat You must review SO's guidelines on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); amongst other things, you should always ask one question at a time; fundamentally changing the question after you've already gotten answers is considered very poor form, as it renders existing questions seemingly useless. Don't keep asking follow-up questions once you've received an answer. Spend time understanding solutions, do research yourself, and if you have a *new* issue ask a *new* question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check capital words in text and extract it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223366/check-capital-words-in-text-and-extract-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, although it will be case sensitive.

First, you need to rename the abstract variable (it can't end in .txt and be considered a string):

```
abstract_text =  "The insulin-like growth factor 1 (IGF1) signaling pathway has emerged..."
```

Then you NEED a list for all the genes you want to search for:

```
genes = ["IGF1"]
```

Then you can search for all the genes.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas

genes_dictionary = {}

for i in genes:
   if i in abstract_text:
      genes_dictionary[i] = 1
```

Convert the dictionary to a table and print it.

```
table = pandas.Series(genes_dictionary, name = 'Count')
table.index.name = 'Gene'
table.reset_index()
```

Output: 

   `Gene  Count
0  IGF1      1`

Comment: thanks for your response arranjdavis. now I want to write this as a table format the column names are name and frequency. this is the small example I have created  for my problem sir. my problem is  I am having a bunch of abstracts where I have been collected from pubmed. now from this abstracts I need to retrive the gene names. can  I know how can I write a code to retrive the gene names from abstracts.

Comment: If you want to make it case insensitive then you could convert both the text and the name to lower case: 

names_dictionary[i] = text.lower().count(i.lower())

Comment: thanks sir. now my requirement is about not case sensitive sir.          I am having a abstracts related to lung cancer. in that abstracts gene names are avilable. now I need to get gene names from this abstracts text file.

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer to what I think you are looking for. Let me know if that works, please.

Comment: yes sir the code was working perfectly. now my requirement is without passing names using regular expressions or any other way to get  names which are included in text file without passing names parameter.

Comment: its good sir. thanks for your responses.  is it possible to get all the names which are included in text file without passing names parameter

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to get all names without passing a names parameter. The function needs to know what to search for. Do all the gene names start with the same string of characters, for example? Also, since I have answered your original question, could you please accept it as 'answered'? Trying to grow my profile a bit :)

Comment: yes arranjdavis I have accepted as answered, now I have edited my question. would you please answer the question. thanki you

Comment: It is not acceptable to completely change a question when editing it, because all previous answers become invalid.

Comment: @arranjdavis Sadly, there's often nothing to gain from feeding the [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). As you already pointed out, this is very poor form from OP; the down-votes to OPs original question reflect the poor quality.

Comment: Venkat, I have again tried to answer your question. I hope it is acceptable. If you have another question, please ask it elsewhere (instead of editing this one again), and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: yes sir. good this is ok where I have tried like this but  without passing gene names  I need to retrive all the gene names avilable in the abstract. let me know the answer sir.

Comment: There is no way that the script can 'know' what a gene name is. You must tell it what the gene names are. To the script, 'dog' and 'IGF1' are the same thing - they are both just strings. You need to tell the script what to look for. If you want help trying to identify gene names in a script, this is another question. You should mark this question as answered, and then start a new, different question, and I will try to help you there.

Comment: arranjdavis sir where can I mark this as question answered like because I don't no this I a new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Venkat, to mark my answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in (it should turn green). Thank you! Here is a more in depth explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: is there any way to retrieve all gene names from pubmed abstracts sir.

Comment: Venkat, I think that this question is best asked by creating a NEW question (you can post the link to this question here so that I can find it). But, like I said before (please pay attention to this) you NEED A LIST OF GENE NAMES to accomplish what you are asking. Perhaps you could get that list from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosome_1). Then you need to search for the genes in this list in the abstracts you have. That is the only way to do it. Unless, all genes are in ALL CAPS in the abstracts, then you could find them like that. But ask a NEW QUESTION - I will answer there.

Answer (score 0):

usually you could do this with table(), but first some preparations:

```
mytxt<-"I am venkatarao.studying matsers. I am going to complete masters. my friends are venkatarao. Naveen, reddy. all are studying masters."

#remove punctations
gsub('[[:punct:]]',' ',mytxt)

#separate words
mytxt<-strsplit(mytxt," ")[[1]]

#frequencies
table(mytxt)
```

However, you wanted only names and there is no way you can do this without predefining what the names are... Or getting a definitionn elsewhere. So taking your definition you could do something like this:

```
find_names<-c("venkatarao","Naveen","reddy","masters")
mytxt[mytxt%in%find_names]
```

Of course this doesn't find names if they are spelled incorrectly ;-)

Comment: thank you for your response.              my aim is I am not going to give the find_names file but result I need to get the all people names what all names avilable in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data set, we can do the foloowing:

```
data.txt = "I am venkatarao.studying matsers. I am going to complete masters. my friends are venkatarao. Naveen, reddy. all are studying masters."

# Isolate words by space, remove periods and commas.
all.words = unlist(strsplit(data.txt, " "))
all.words = unlist(strsplit(all.words, "\\."))
all.words = unlist(strsplit(all.words, "\\,"))

count.table = table(all.words)

# Specify Names you are interested in
> count.table[names(count.table) %in% c("venkatarao", "Naveen")]
all.words
   masters     Naveen      reddy venkatarao 
         2          1          1          2
```

Comment: yes Nishan thankyou. its good this is ok for this example. like this I am having a bunch of abstracts where I have extracted from pubmed. from this abstracts I need to retrive gene names alone. is it possible Nishan. the .txt file contains 300 article abstracts related to diseases. now I want to extract gene names that are included in the .txt  abstracts file.

Comment: @Venkat you can create a vector of all gene names and then see which ones are in the text file. if `gene.names` is your vector, then change the code to `count.table[names(count.table) %in% gene.names]`